# having issue with array code, java based coding

Tags: java, arrays

Bare in mind that I am just a beginner in java. The question is  to  accept ten numbers from the user, store them in an array and find the highest, lowest and average value of the ten numbers. Then extends the above program to rearrange all the numbers in an increasing order of value i.e. sort the numbers. Write an explanation of the sorting logic/algorithm you have used.

I use Netbeans to do java coding as advised by my lecturer.

the code does not compile to what is required to do.

Below is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class lowhighavg 
{
    private static int [] array;
    private static int i;

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        int numbers[] = new int[10],highest=0, lowest=0;
        double avg;
        avg = 00;
        Scanner sc = new scanner(System.in);

        for (int i=0, i<10;i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter a digit");
            number[i]= sc.nextInt();
            avg = avg+number[i];
        }

        highest = number[0];
        lowest = number[0];

        for (int i=0; i< numbers.length; i++);
        {
            if (numbers [i] > highest)
                highest= numbers[i];
        }

        if (number [i] < lowest)
        {
            lowest = numbers[i];
        }

        System.out.println("the highest number:" + highest);
        System.out.println("the lowest number:" + lowest);

        avg =avg/10;

        System.out.println("the average number:" + avg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Point of advice. Try Alt-shift-F in netbeans. Also, the semi-colon after `for (int i=0; i< numbers.length; i++);` screws it up, it shouldn't be there.

Comment: What is the quetsion?

Comment: *"the code does not compile to what is required to do."* ... well, that's because it contains syntax errors. And once you fix those, it contains logical errors. We're not here to do your homework for you.

Comment: it does but I am a beginner and im not sure how I can view the errors and suggestions, @BrianRoach im not asking for the answer, im asking for help as a java student.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's quite a few errors in the code example you posted before, but others have already pointed that out.

To find highest and lowest, simply use Arrays utility class and sort the array, and simply pick the first and last values of array after its been sorted (I fixed the syntax errors):

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class lowhighavg 
{
    private static int [] array;
    private static int i;

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        int numbers[] = new int[10];
        double avg;
        avg = 00;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter a digit");
            numbers[i]= sc.nextInt();
            avg = avg+numbers[i];
        }

        Arrays.sort(numbers);

        System.out.println("the highest number:" + numbers[numbers.length-1]);
        System.out.println("the lowest number:" + numbers[0]);

        avg =avg/10;

        System.out.println("the average number:" + avg);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much! I see that I have mixed up some terms and some basic mistakes, sorry I am still a rookie

Comment: im sorry to ask again but how will I display the number in ascending order?

Comment: Arrays.sort(numbers); 
System.out.println("the lowest number:" + Arrays.sort(numbers));

is it right?

Comment: No, Arrays.toString(numbers).

Answer (score 0):

- The syntax on your first for-loop is wrong. The individual segments
  should be semi-colon separated.

  ```
  for (int i=0, i<10;i++) // Change the comma here
  ```
- Java is a case-sensitive language. `Scanner` should be uppercase on
  the right-hand side of this expression.

  ```
  Scanner sc = new scanner(System.in);
  ```
- You've also declared an int array named `numbers` but there's several
  instances in your code where you're referring to an undeclared
  variable `number`.

You also have a semi-colon at the end of your second for-loop. It's like saying "execute nothing x amount of times" and it also has the effect that the following if-statement will only be executed after that loop is over resulting in your highest number staying as the first element of the array. The other if-statement to find the lowest number should probably be inside that loop too.

I also don't understand why you have two static variables since you're apparently not using them anywhere. The fact that you had `i` declared as static probably hid one of the aforementioned errors.

Comment: thanks buddy, i'm not quite sure where or how to insert the code to sort the results in ascending order also?

Comment: nobody seem to pick up on that in the question

Comment: @user3294763: As suggested in the other two answers you can just use [`Arrays.sort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(int[])). You can place it anywhere after you've finished reading in the user's input.

Comment: could you please give me a simple example please?

Answer (score 0):

This part is clearly wrong:

```
for (int i=0; i< numbers.length; i++);
    {
        if (numbers [i] > highest)
            highest= numbers[i];
    }

    if (number [i] < lowest)
    {
        lowest = numbers[i];
    }
```

It should be something like this:

```
for (int i=0; i< numbers.length; i++)
{
    if (numbers [i] > highest)
        highest= numbers[i];


    if (numbers [i] < lowest)
    {
        lowest = numbers[i];
    }
}
```

You can use `Arrays.sort(numbers)` to sort the numbers.

Comment: hey, thanks for your corrections, it has helped me a lot!